# What is the [pod] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a tag called [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) that is being used in multiple unrelated contexts.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5229117) is the suggested edit that caused me to notice this:

> - in Perl language it means **Plain Old Documentation**, a platform-independent
>         documentation tool for the language;
> - in Python language it means **Python Open Document**;
> - in C++, it means [**Plain Old Data**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure);
> - in C#, a pod is an artifact of the dependency manager [cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoapods);
> - other usages are possible like **Point Of Delivery** (networking), **Power-On Diagnostics** (embedded programming) or **Ping Of Death** (system security).

Most tags seem to have a single set meaning, is it acceptable to have a tag's meaning get overloaded like this?

Comment: Nope. The stuff all needs to be retagged. This is exactly why acronyms suck as tags.

Comment: I thought cocoa pods were an objective-c thing.

Comment: Aside from the ambiguous acronym, this tag did not have any definition/description at all until it was just added. Shouldn't all tags have at least a minimal description? Sorry if this is a naïve question, I haven't really done tag maintenance, except for reviewing the re-tags that come up in the edit review queue.

Comment: I am the original author of the suggestion. I suggested the new meaning, because it is effectively used in questions. The proper thing to do should have been to edit the questions and remove/replace the tag?

Comment: @animuson: What should the Plain Old Documentation questions be retagged as? I don’t see a [tag:plain-old-documentation], and I think everyone refers to it as POD rather than expanding the initialism.

Comment: @AustinMullins yes, and this is what I meant to type. Not sure what my fingers were thinking... That makes this suggestion even worse...

Comment: @RetoKoradi Actually the edit page forces you to add an excerpt when there isn't one. I guess this is recent, as I have seen that in my previous tag edits (or maybe I always provided an excerpt).

Comment: @icktoofay [Perlpod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) seems to be how it's referred in the Perl documentation. So why not create that tag?

Comment: @animuson: That’s only the name of the manual page, and that’s because [everything starts with `perl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html). In the text, it’s always Pod.

Comment: @icktoofay So what's wrong with that being the tag name? It's a lot better than an ambiguous pod tag.

Comment: It's also mean  plain old datastructure in c++

Comment: @xyz: Actually it means "Plain Old Data".

Comment: I'm assuming that "perl-plain-old-documentation" and "c++-plain-old-data" would be considered too wordy? ...an assumption with which I'd agree, since my fingers got tired *typing* them.

Comment: [There is a 90's version of POD too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhJfdWxpI2Q), but I think we're all trying to forget about that forever.

Comment: Is it possible to make all of the potential expansions appear as suggestions if someone types "pod" in the tags box?  (If we don't make that happen somehow, I suspect this tag will just reappear in short order...(

Comment: @Djizeus Yes. The proper thing to do would be to move 'pod' to 'cocoapod' for all questions where that is matching. Maybe 'cocoapod-pod' if a distinction to 'cocoapod' is necessary.