# Burninate the [pod] bay doors please, Trogdor

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) specifically states in its [tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pod/info) that it shouldn't be used:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Instead, prefer a specific tag like [kubernetes-pod] or [cocoapods].

Moreover, the tag-wiki specifically states that *pod* have several different meanings in different contexts, so it shouldn't be used as a general tag.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   To some extent it does describe the contents of the question, however due to the fact that it has very different meanings depending on the context it is applied to it is not unambiguous.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Yes, all 8 meanings described in the tag-wiki are related to programming and are on-topic for the site. Most of the questions currently using the tag are also on-topic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Due to the ambiguity around the whole tag, it's hard to say that anyone would be following the tag or that it would help anyone find a question or even clarify the topic of a question using the tag.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

The tag-wiki specifically mentions at least 8 different meanings for pod depending on the context it is applied to, so no.

Can we burninate this tag?

Comment: Note that there are [several C++ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod%20c%2b%2b) in there too. I'm not quite sure how to handle that, since C++ (until 20) has POD as a concept.

Comment: @NicolBolas I suppose creating a specific tag for those would make sense

Comment: It is also the name of the documentation system in Perl with [37 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod+perl) (at the time of this comment).

Comment: This tag seems to no longer exist. Should this be status-complete?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this tag should be burninated. Firstly, as you precise, it fits the criteria for burnination.

Additionally, there is a great confusion about the usefulness of such a tag. In [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262736/what-is-the-pod-tag-for), several moderators and experienced users basically agreed that:

- The plural-set meaning was not acceptable for a tag
- There is no built-in alert mechanism when someone is about to tag a question with [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod)
- Sub-meanings of `pod` can be moved into new or existing tags ([perl-pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-pod), [cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoapods), `c++-pod`...)

Moreover, another user and I [recently approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22562109) an edit where someone added [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) on a [cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoapods) question. It really seemed logic to me: Kubernetes pods and Cocoapods are somewhat similar and I reasonably guessed that adding [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) would precise a software development concept that would make the question more accessible and understandable... I got review-banned for this, and I guess the other reviewer too.

It's a waste of reviewers' efforts to expect them to dive into the tag wikis of each added tag to check on whether or not the tag should still be used or not. Just burninate the tags that are, by definition, unusable.

Comment: Why do you think [[tag:perl-pod]] or [[tag:c++-pod]] is any better than [[tag:perl]]+[[tag:pod]]?

Comment: Well, firstly because [tag:pod] is not supposed to be used, which makes everything better than [tag:pod] + *