# Clean up [pod] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, blocklist-request

The word *Pod* is used in many different context and has very different meaning in each context. I suggest that the tag should be cleaned up and the questions should be tagged with more specific tags and then the [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) could be added to the block-list?

### Separate meanings of "Pod"

This can be explored with this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod%20-kubernetes%20-cocoapods%20-ios%20-openshift%20-swift%20-react-native%20-flutter%20-c%2b%2b%20-xcode%20-perl?tab=newest&page=1&pagesize=15), of 555 [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) tags, all except 55 is excluded with:

```
[pod] -[kubernetes] -[cocoapods] -[ios] -[openshift] -[swift] -[react-native] -[flutter] -[c++] -[xcode] -[perl] -[docker]
```

#### iOS dependency management

The questions related to iOS development is in most cases related to [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) dependency management:

> CocoaPods is a dependency manager for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects. It has over 79 thousand libraries and is used in over 3 million apps.

Related tags that all should most likely use [cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoapods) instead of [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod):

- [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)
- [cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoapods)
- [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)
- [react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native)
- [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter)
- [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode)

#### Kubernetes

The Kubernetes related questions use the Pod term related to [Kubernetes Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) which is a grouping of containers and the unit of scheduling.

> Pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can create and manage in Kubernetes.

Related tags that should most likely use [kubernetes-pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-pod) instead of [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) or can [perhaps use [kubernetes] tag without specific pod-tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404196/synonymize-kubernetes-pods-with-kubernetes):

- [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes)
- [openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openshift)
- [minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minikube)
- [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker)

#### Perl documentation

The questions related to [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) and [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) is in most cases related to [Plain Old Documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod) and can instead be tagged with [perl-pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-pod).

#### C++

The questions related to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is in most cases related to [Plain Old Data Type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) and may [perhaps not need its own tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304229/nuke-and-blacklist-all-of-the-tags-for-fundamental-programming-concepts)

### Finally

When the tag is cleaned up, it should perhaps be added to a block-list to avoid the above described confusion?

Comment: It has to be burninated and then reappear before it's eligible for blacklisting. In favor of burning it, though. Extremely ambiguous tag

Comment: Open the `[pod]` bay doors, HAL.

Comment: Should it be `[perl-pod]` or `[pod-perl]`?

Comment: @TimurShtatland that tags I relate to already exists, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-pod however, I now think [perl-pod] should be a synonym to [perldoc] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perldoc but that is a different question :)

Comment: The [pod]s of dolphins are coming by!

Comment: `perldoc` technically refers to the Perl language documentation (which happens to be written in POD) as well as a command line utility to view both the Perl documentation as well as a renderer for POD in files written in Perl. As a Perl person, I wouldn't use `perldoc` to refer to questions about the POD language. The description of the `[perlpod]` tag seems accurate for this.

Comment: Related: [What is the \[pod\] tag for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262736/1478931) And a previous burnination of the same tag: [Burninate the \[pod\] bay doors please, Trogdor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366760/1478931)

Comment: What do y'all think about using this as suggested guidance when someone attempts to use this tag: `Please use a more specific tag to describe the subject of your question, such as [cocoapods](/tags/cocoapods), [kubernetes-pod](/tags/kubernetes-pod), or [perl-pod](/tags/perl-pod).`? (cc @ZoestandswithUkraine )

Comment: @V2Blast No objections from me

Comment: @V2Blast will it be a tag warning or a tag block?

Comment: @Braiam: A tag block, since that's what was requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) tag is now blocked on Stack Overflow. Anyone attempting to add the [pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pod) tag to their question will be shown the following message:

> The 'pod' tag is not allowed.
>
> Please use a more specific tag to describe the subject of your question, such as [cocoapods](/tags/cocoapods), [kubernetes-pod](/tags/kubernetes-pod), or [perl-pod](/tags/perl-pod).